# Pledge (pledʒ) pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

I'm wondering if 'pledge' could be or is somewhere in the nowadays English world pronounced as 'plidʒ'.

As I found (though seems not to be very reliable as it is only one source) pledge had the synonym [pleedge](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/dsl/getent4.php?dtext=both&query=PLEDGE) but seems to be gone.

Though, [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/pledge) only proposes two main pronunciations.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Under "forms", OED lists *ME plech, ME plegg, ME–15 plegge, ME–16 plege, lME– pledge, 15–16 pledg, 16 pleg; Sc. pre-17 pladge, pre-17 pladgies (plural), pre-17 plaege, pre-17 plage, pre-17 plaig, pre-17 plaige, pre-17 pleadge, pre-17 pleage, pre-17 pledg, pre-17 pledgies (plural), pre-17 pleg, pre-17 plege, pre-17 plegge, pre-17 plegies (plural), pre-17 plegyis (plural), pre-17 pleidge, pre-17 pleige, pre-17 pliege, pre-17 17– pledge, pre-17 (19– Shetland) plaidge, 18 pleedge (Caithness).* But current standard spelling and orthography is always **pledge = /pledʒ/**.

Comment: What makes you ask?  Did you hear someone say it this way?  Is there any more information you can add?

Comment: @snailboa, well there is that entry from the [Dictionary of the Scots Language](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/). The matter with the pronunciation is only for rhythm concerns for a 'poem' I'm writting

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thank you, seems like there is another source for pleedge, even though it seems to no longer be used.

Comment: It’s not quite clear to me whether you’re using phonemic transcription (in which case /i/ represents a long vowel, [iː]) or phonetic transcription (in which case [i] is to be taken literally as a short vowel). Short [i] does not occur in stressed syllables in any English dialect (though Australian /ɪ/ is quite close to it), but in New Zealand, /ɛ/ is pronounced [e̝] or [i̞], which will often sound much like [i] to speakers of different dialects. /ɛ/ is the phoneme found in ‘pledge’, which in New Zealand is pronounced [pʰle̝ʤ] or [pʰli̞ʤ]. If you meant [iː], then no. No dialect pronounces that.

Comment: @sabotero: I think you'll have to settle for a "half-rhyme" - it would be a bit weird to expect readers of your "poem" to accept an obscure and archaic dialectal variant purely for the sake of rhyme.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, yes I think I should take 'pledge' as it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I mean this [plidʒ] as in this [entry](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/dsl/getent4.php?dtext=both&query=PLEDGE) , but you are right, it is not clear even for me as I'm not an expert reading phonetic/phonemic transcriptions, does this [i] sounds as 'i' in 'me'?

Comment: In some contexts, the dated/archaic verb *plight* is synonymous with *pledge* (e.g. - *"Plight one's troth"*). It's not etymologically related, but I suppose this could have affected use and pronunciation in the past.

Comment: Someone voting down, leave at least an explanation. Do you at least understand the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Scottish people will understand *pleege* or probably better *pleedge* to mean *pledge* as long as the rest of your poem uses a Scottish accent. I would imagine most English people could also work it out.

> Wi' a' the lassies in ma reach,
>
> A lovin' hert a huv to pleedge,
>
> A' asked them a' in saftest speech,
>
> Gang wi' me noo, aff doon the beach

However this would not work if your poem is written in normal English

> All the girls within my reach,
>
> A loving heart I have to pledge,
>
> I asked them all in softest speech,
>
> Come with me now, off to the beach

I doubt even real Scottish people would make the connection between *pledge* (as they read it) and *pleedge* as they might say it sometimes.

Excuse my poetry and my 'Scottish'

Comment: Thank you, I understood your point. I will have to settle for a 'half-rhythm' as FumbleFingers suggested